# how to add a list under one tag in yaml file by Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to make one YAML file by python like as below.

```
A:
  B:
    - c: d
```

but if I do it as follows:

```
data = {'A':{'B':{'- c':'d'}}}
yaml.dump(data,file,default_flow_style = False)
```

the output in the file is as below:

```
A:
  B:
    '-c': d
```

How can I get rid of the quotation around the `- c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes are there because the `-` is a reserved word. If you want to make a sequence in YAML you have include a list in Python, and you only have dictionaries (which are output as mappings).

Try:

```
data = {'A':{'B': [{'c':'d'}]}}
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, default_flow_style = False)
```

which gets you:

```
A:
  B:
  - c: d
```

Comment: @subhadip If this solves your issue, please consider accepting this answer (by clicking the V mark on the left side). That shows others that show other that your issue was solved as well (and gives me a few reputation points)

Comment: Anthon . i have another question similar to this as below.

Comment: I want to make one yaml file by python like as below.

    A:
      B:
         c: {d:e}

but if i do it like as below:

    data = {'A':{'B':{ 'c':'{d:e}'}}}
    yaml.dump(data,file,default_flow_style = False)

the output in the file is as below:

    A:
      B:
        c: '{d: e}'

i dont want the quotation around . how to make it. please help

Comment: @subhadip It is hard to see what you are doing with the limited formatting a comment allows. It looks like you put quotes around a value that is a complex structure, which makes Python think it is a string. If that doesn't solve it you should really post that as a new question (you can ping me with a comment here if you do, but I get around to most python+YAML questions anyway)